# In JavaScript, retrieve the value and performed the addition after that want to return the value after the for loop in cypress automation?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

```
verifyActiveInterfacesViaConnectionStatus() {
        var sum = 0
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            cy.xpath(`(//*[name()='g' and @class ='highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-undefined']//*[name()='text']//*[@class='highcharts-text-outline'])[${i}]`).invoke("text").then(($text1) => {

               var textValue1 = $text1 + "\n"
               cy.log(textValue1)
               var  total = parseInt(textValue1)
               sum += total
            })
        }
        cy.log("Total of all connected OS= " + sum)
    }
```

In the cypress automation, when I'm running this block of code it is returning the sum=0 but I don't know why it is displaying 0. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypress commands are asynchronous.
`cy.log` captures the `sum` value *before* the first `xpath` command gets really executed.
To synchronize access to the `sum` you can use a then callback:

```js
verifyActiveInterfacesViaConnectionStatus() {
        var sum = 0
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            cy.xpath(`(//*[name()='g' and @class ='highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-undefined']//*[name()='text']//*[@class='highcharts-text-outline'])[${i}]`).invoke("text").then(($text1) => {

               var textValue1 = $text1 + "\n"
               cy.log(textValue1)
               var  total = parseInt(textValue1)
               sum += total
            })
        }
        cy.then(() => {
           cy.log("Total of all connected OS= " + sum)
        })
    }
```

Look at [this article](https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-variables) for details on how to handle variables at Cypress.

Comment: Hii... Thank you so mush buddy for the solution this is working fine.
Can you tell where can I learn these basic that is related to asynchronous and synchronize  access.
Thanks again!!

Comment: I added the link